# Is $V=\textsf{HOD}\not\Rightarrow\textsf{GCH}$ consistent?

Tags: set-theory, inner-model-theory, gch

Whenever $M$ is some fine-structural $L$-like model we can prove the implication $V=M\Rightarrow\textsf{GCH}$. For $L$ this is due to Gödel, and for the modern extender models it follows simply by construction. The most recent direction in the inner model programme searches for fine-structural models of the form $\textsf{HOD}^N$ with $N$ some "nice" model (most [recently](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~uhlenbrock/MuellerSargsyanHODMnxG.pdf) this includes $N=M_n(x,g)$ for a Turing cone of reals $x$ and $g$ generic for making its least $N$-inaccessible countable). My question is then whether $V=\textsf{HOD}\Rightarrow\textsf{GCH}$ has been shown to be unprovable in general (modulo large cardinals of course)? Is there some pathological $\textsf{HOD}$ which "obviously" doesn't satisfy $\textsf{GCH}$? Also, I'm not even sure if $\textsf{HOD}^{\textsf{HOD}^N}=\textsf{HOD}^N$ holds for these models, as this (apparently) doesn't hold in general.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, one can produce a model of $ZFC+V=HOD$ in which the $CH$ fails. This should follow from [Consistency results about ordinal definability](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484371900052?via%3Dihub).

In fact, I think the arguments of my paper   [HOD, V and the GCH](http://math.ipm.ac.ir/~golshani/Papers/HOD,%20V%20and%20the%20GCH.pdf) can be used to produce a model of $ZFC+V=HOD$ in which the $GCH$ fails everywhere.

Also by a result of Apter (see [Large cardinals need not be large in HOD](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~sdf/papers/joint.joel.yong.pdf) for a proof), if there are class many Laver indestructible supercompact cardinals, then $V=HOD$ holds. Note that in such a model $GCH$ must fail at class many regular cardinals.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the swift answer Mohammad!
I also tried digging through the citations in the papers you mentioned, and found where this was perhaps first shown (in the weakest form): in McAloon ('70) he shows that $V=\textsf{HOD}+\lnot\textsf{CH}$ is consistent.

Comment: Possibly a silly question - why must GCH fail frequently in a model with class many Laver indestructible supercompacts?

Comment: @Noah For instance, $\mathsf{GCH}$ cannot first fail above a supercompact $\kappa$, but you can violate it with $\kappa$-directed closed forcing. So, if $\kappa$ is Laver indestructible, $\mathsf{GCH}$ must fail (frequently) below $\kappa$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Ah, yes, silly of me.